# missing 'your number is right' sentence

Tags: java

i have coded a simple random number generator that u need to guess with what number it is but for some reason it wont print out if the number u entered is correct. can someone please have a look at this?
im a noob in java btw... learning myself..

```
package randomnumbergenerator;
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class main {
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        System.out.println("Enter the lowest border");
        Scanner scannerx = new Scanner(System.in);
        int y = scannerx.nextInt();
        System.out.println("Enter the highest border");
        Scanner scannery = new Scanner(System.in);
        int x = scannery.nextInt();
        Random random = new Random();
        int randomnummer = random.nextInt(x) + y;
        System.out.println("Now try to guess the number!");
        Scanner guessingnumber = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guessednumber = guessingnumber.nextInt();
        while(randomnummer != guessednumber){   
            if (randomnummer == guessednumber){
            System.out.println("you guessed it right!");
            }
            if(randomnummer >= guessednumber){
            System.out.println("the number you guessed it wrong, its higher!");
            }
            if(randomnummer <= guessednumber){
            System.out.println("the number you guessed it wrong, its lower!");
            }
            System.out.println("try again!");
            Scanner guessingnumber1 = new Scanner(System.in);
            guessednumber = guessingnumber1.nextInt();
        }
    }
```

}
thanks in advance!

Comment: You are openning a new `Scanner` each time tou want to read something... this is not necessary, use a single one

Comment: i do have to do that, since i want to put something else in everytime the condition isnt met

Comment: Yeah, but you can reuse the same `Scanner` several times !

Answer (score 6):

Your line `if (randomnummer == guessednumber){` is inside a while loop that says `while(randomnummer != guessednumber)`. Those two conditions can't both be true, so the `if` condition will never be met.

You could move the "You guessed right" message to after the end of the `while` loop.

Comment: I thought I would also mention that the conditionals checking for greater than or less than should be '>' and '<' rather than '>=' and '<='

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
while(randomnummer != guessednumber){   

   if(randomnummer > guessednumber){
       System.out.println("the number you guessed it wrong, its higher!");
   } else {
       System.out.println("the number you guessed it wrong, its lower!");
   }
   System.out.println("try again!");
   Scanner guessingnumber1 = new Scanner(System.in);
   guessednumber = guessingnumber1.nextInt();
}

System.out.println("you guessed it right!");
```